# sparql pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, rdf, sparql

I'm currently learning some sparql and I'm practicing on the following website with some statements:

http://data.semanticweb.org/snorql

However, I'm trying to execute the following statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?author WHERE { ?paper swrc:author ?author FILTER(regex(?paper, "2006")) . } .
```

It says that there are no results. When I run the following query (without the filter):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?paper WHERE { ?paper swrc:author ?author . }
```

I see that there are some papers with 2006 in it's string. I'm wondering why the first query is not returning these entries where there is 2006 in the ?paper string.

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RDF terms returned for `?paper` are all URIs. The `REGEX` filter function doesn't work on URIs; it only works on strings. You can turn a URI into a string using the `STR(…)` function. This will work:

```
FILTER(regex(STR(?paper), "2006"))
```

Comment: One could also specifically query for a year using a property present in the SWRC ontology `SELECT DISTINCT ?paper ?year WHERE { ?paper swrc:author ?author .
?paper swrc:year ?year }`. Unfortunately the papers from 2006 seem to lack this property.